# Security Issues by calling require() with untrusted string (require.js)

Tags: javascript, security, requirejs

My browser application uses require.js. The app displays one of many different widgets on the the screen. The URL fragment contains the path to a widget (a require.js path) and then there is a call to require to dynamically load it:

```
var moduleName = getUrlFragement('widget'); // accesses window.location
require(moduleName);
```

moduleName is an **untrusted** string. The user can make it whatever they want.

What are the security issues with this?

Here are my own findings so far:

- An attacker cannot load an arbitrary URL from a different domain
- An attacker cannot load an arbitrary URL from the same domain
- An attacker **can** force the loading of any module my application defines, which would run any initialization logic that module has. **This should not be allowed**.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Can you require/enforce that the module is only located in one particular path location on your server where there are only modules that you know are safe?  So, you allow the end-user to specify only the base filename, but not the path and you append the "safe" path to the name that the user provides.

Comment: Yes, enforcing some constraints is easily done. I already know that I will not allow users to load arbitrary modules.What I'd like to know is if my analysis captured all of the security concerns.

Comment: The challenge here is that you haven't disclosed the more interesting parts of the problem.  If a user can place any module on the server and then execute that module, that means they can execute ANY code they want.  If they can only execute modules already placed on the machine, then the vulnerability depends entirely upon what modules are in a place they can access and what those modules do.  If they can only execute a restricted set of modules, then it depends entirely upon what that restricted set of modules do.  So, the vulnerability depends upon what modules they have access to execute.

Comment: Users cannot put modules on the server.

Comment: Then, why don't you allow the user to specify a filename ONLY (no path) and you put a path onto the module name and you make sure that only safe modules are located in that path?  You will have to reject any illegal names that are specifying path characters to enforce that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have done. There is a whitelist of modules. But I think I understand your answer to my original question: there are no security issues beyond what I listed.

Comment: Notice that the attack vector you describe is not really accurate. A user can load and run any arbitrary code in his browser anyway. The security issue stems from third parties assembling urls that make your users execute untrusted modules unknowingly.

Comment: @Bergi how is what you describe different from the third bullet point?

Comment: @JenS.: You say "a user can". Every user can by himself. The actual problem is that *other people* can make your users download and execute code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. You have captured the security issues completely and accurately.